# SQL sum a field grouped by same identifier in two different columns

Tags: mysql, sql

The table has 4 columns Match, Winning_Player_ID, Losing_Player_ID, Quantity_Points_Exchanged_for_that_match. I would like to in a single query show the total number of points each player won and earned over all matches.

Here is the table

```
M WIN LOSE QTY  
1 100 201 10  
2 201 100 05  
3 100 201 05  
4 302 100 05
```

For output I would like total it in this way in a single query and cannot figure it out.

```
ID WIN LOSE
100 15 10
201 05 15
302 05 00
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT p.player ID,
       (SELECT SUM(QTY) FROM tbl WHERE WIN = p.player) WIN,
       (SELECT SUM(QTY) FROM tbl WHERE LOSE = p.player) LOSE
FROM
    (SELECT DISTINCT WIN player FROM tbl
    UNION
    SELECT DISTINCT LOSE FROM tbl) p
```

Comment: This SQL doesn't work.  Where is QTY coming from?  The FROM clause only has table with one column, player.

Comment: This SQL [works](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6246d/1). The table has QTY column. The performance is entirely another matter however.

Comment: This works and is very slow. I finally just wound up turning each record into two records, a win for on and a loss for the other.

Comment: I finally just wound up turning each record into two records, a win for one and a loss for the other and storing win or lose in a field called result.  The SQL looks like this: SELECT `id`, SUM(IF(`result`='win',`quantity`,0)) as win,
SUM(IF(`result`='lose',`quantity`,0)) as lose FROM `games` group by id;

Answer (score 1):

No db available to check this out, but perhaps something like this:

```
SELECT player, SUM(winQty) AS WIN, SUM(loseQty) AS LOSE
  FROM ( SELECT win AS player, qty AS winQty, 0 AS loseQty
           FROM myTable
         UNION ALL
         SELECT lose AS player, 0 AS winQty, qty AS loseQty
           FROM myTable
       ) x
  GROUP BY player
```

UPDATE: Changed UNION to UNION ALL

Answer (score 0):

Here's the answer:

CREATE THE TABLE:

```
CREATE TABLE table_name (
  m int,
  win int,
  lose int,
  qty int);
```

INSERT THE DATA:

```
INSERT INTO table_name (m, win, lose, qty)
values 
(1, 100, 201, 10),
(2, 201, 100, 05),
(3, 100, 201, 05),
(4, 302, 100, 05);
```

The QUERY:

```
SELECT id, sum(won), sum(lost) from (
    SELECT win as id, SUM(qty) as won, 0 as lost 
    FROM table_name W GROUP BY win
  UNION
    SELECT lose as id, 0 as won, SUM(qty) as lost
    FROM table_name W GROUP BY lose
  ) sums
GROUP BY ID
```

The result:

```
+------+----------+-----------+
| id   | sum(won) | sum(lost) |
+------+----------+-----------+
|  100 |       15 |        10 |
|  201 |        5 |        15 |
|  302 |        5 |         0 |
+------+----------+-----------+
```

Comment: If by OUTER JOIN you mean FULL OUTER JOIN, it's not supported in MySQL. Besides this won't [work](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/6246d/1) on database that supports FULL OUTER JOIN, e.g. SQL Server. Will upvote if it works even it's on another database platform

Comment: That's right -- I'd forgotten that MySQL doesn't support full outer joins. Let me rethink it.

Comment: Now it's almost identical to another answer

Comment: I didn't look at the other answers. I just built it up from scratch -- you have the code, run it.

Comment: @Kevin Bedell: I'm not OP. And I pointed out that there is another answer which follows the similar idea with less keystrokes

Comment: With MySQL lacking of full outer join, you cannot do it in another way. Union is the only intuitive way to do it in MySQL. This has a feel of Oracle vs Google's rangeCheck ツ

Comment: The code above is MySQL. Just run it -- it's all there. It works.