# Sum of a field for every user but Grouped in two columns

Tags: select, sqlite

```
CREATE TABLE [arsenal] (
  [id] INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, 
  [agent] INTEGER NOT NULL, 
  [haul] DECIMAL NOT NULL, 
  [target] INTEGER NOT NULL);

INSERT INTO arsenal (agent, haul, target) VALUES (1, 10, 2), (1, 100, 2), (2, 20, 1), (2, 200, 1);
```

I have a table which looks like this. I want to get sum of all `haul`s for each user, but users are spread in two columns `agent` and `target`. For eg, agent with user id = 1 has a sum of 110 while the same user in target field has a sum of 220. So the effective sum is 110 + 220 = 330. Similarly user id = 2 has an effective sum of 330 (220 in agent column and 110 in target column).

If my source is:

```
id  agent   haul    target
1      1     10        2
2      1     100       2
3      2     20        1
4      2     200       1
```

, I need the output:

```
user haul
1    330
2    330
```

. I can achieve that with:

```
SELECT   user, SUM(sum) 
FROM     ( 
          SELECT   agent AS user, SUM(haul) AS sum
          FROM     arsenal 
          GROUP BY agent

          UNION ALL

          SELECT   target, SUM(haul)
          FROM     arsenal 
          GROUP BY target
         ) AS t

GROUP BY user;
```

I'm trying to get rid of the Union since the actual select queries around Union All are a bit more complex and so I assuming that's a bottleneck. Is there a better way to achieve this, may be without sub-queries?

[Here's a very similar thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10645194/sql-sum-a-field-grouped-by-same-identifier-in-two-different-columns) but the answers don't appeal to me. Thanks

**Edit:** Here's the actual query:

```
SELECT   user, SUM(sum) 
FROM     ( 
          SELECT   agent AS user, SUM(haul) AS sum
          FROM     arsenal AS a

          JOIN bucket AS b ON b.parent_id=a.id
          JOIN region AS r ON r.terminal = b.terminal
          WHERE a.status=@status AND r.savedStatus=@savedStatus

          GROUP BY agent

          UNION ALL

          SELECT   target, SUM(haul)
          FROM     arsenal 

          JOIN bucket AS b ON b.parent_id=a.id
          JOIN region AS r ON r.terminal = b.terminal
          WHERE a.status=@status AND r.savedStatus=@savedStatus

          GROUP BY target
         ) AS t

GROUP BY user;
```

Additionally it has more fields in `SELECT`s. The thing to notice here is that it's the exact same query that's being run twice in both `SELECT`s in `UNION`. So I'm trying to avoid the `UNION` altogether and rely on some sort of `JOIN` or so to avoid the redundancy.

Comment: Do you have a `User` table we could join on?  Also, with this data structure, union is likely to be a very good option; don't assume it's the bottle neck.  And what does the rest of your code look like, this can really make a difference to the most performany answer.  And, are you in a position to change your data structure?  Doing so will likely give more options for better performance with less/simpler code

Comment: @Dems Yes I do have User table, and the `JOIN`s take place. I posted only a sample. The rest of the part include 1) simple JOIN to get user from user table, which is plain simple, 2) In the inner query around the UNION it does some additional `JOIN`s and nothing else. But both are just the same code. I'll post it. But I do not think that's the bottleneck

Comment: @Dems what structural change do you recommend? I'm eager to know if that can be incorporated

Answer (score 2):

To avoid the union you ***could*** join on another table to effectively double the number of row.  *(Your UNION ALL currently does the doubling of rows.)*

```
  Agent
INNER JOIN
  Haul
    ON Agent.ID = Haul.Agent
    OR Agent.ID = Haul.Target
```

But a join can only use one index.  And no sinlgle index fulfils the OR condition at all effectively.  *You can't sort the records such that you meet Both of these criteria; the Records for the same Agent are next to each other AND the Records for the same Target are next to each other.)*

The *usual* SQL Code optimisation here is the UNION ALL that you don't like.

This could be solved by moving the Agent and Target fields out into a normalised table, with the following fields:
- Haul_ID
- Agent_ID
- Is_Target

This will have two records per Haul already...

```
  HaulAgentMap
INNER JOIN
  Haul
    ON Haul.ID = HaulAgentMap.Haul_ID
```

A single index on HaulAgentMap will also keep all the appropriate records next to each other.

In ***general*** this type of normalisation benefits your code AND the performance.  As well as maintainability, adaptability, etc, etc

(Sorry for any mistakes, I'm on a phone...)

**EDIT**

To reduce repetition in your code, but not likely changing performance, you could just join on the union...

```
(
  SELECT id, Agent, val FROM haul
  UNION ALL
  SELECT id, Target, val FROM haul
)
  AS haul
INNER JOIN
  etc, etc
```

The RDBMS will normally expand this out when generating the query plan.  In other words, it will act like your original query, but with less repetition in your code.

Comment: You can normalize db tables while talking to someone on phone? Man you can change the world! Are you Jon Skeet in disguise? :P Gimme some time to evaluate. Thanks!